# VBA Excel ADO SQL Update Query Not Working

Tags: sql, excel, vba, scripting, ado

I am new to VBA and Excel Scripting, however, I am trying to use it to connect to an SQL Server I have created. I have built a generalized query from a userform, and created a successful SELECT statements that fill my sheet.

However, when I try to update this information in the database I am unsuccessful. The code throws no errors, but I cannot find my changes in the database. Here is my attempt:

```vb
Private Sub dbUpdate(Query)

Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim recset As ADODB.Recordset
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim strConn As String

'Create the connection string
strConn = "Provider=SQLNCLI11;Server=IP-Address;Database=Info;Trusted_Connection=yes;DataTypeCompatibility=80;"

'Create the connection and recordset objects
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
Set recset = New ADODB.Recordset

'Open the connection
conn.Open strConn

'Open the recordset with the query
'Previous attempt, no errors
'recset.Open Query, conn

'Execute the recordset
Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
'The below execution of a query throws errors I believe
cmd.CommandText = Query
Set recset = cmd.Execute

'Close things up
Set recset = Nothing
'recset.Close
conn.Close
Set conn = Nothing

End Sub
```

I am pretty sure the query is correct, but I will update tomorrow if I still can't figure it out.

Comment: Your code does nothing to try to update the data. You didn't include the contents of `Query`, so it's pretty difficult to figure out what might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one example that could work for you.

```
Sub ImportDataFromExcel()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim r As Long
    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim strConn As String
    Dim strSQL As String

    strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & _
        "C:\Users\Ryan\Desktop\Coding\Integrating Access and Excel and SQL Server\Access & Excel & SQL Server\" & _
        "EXCEL AND ACCESS AND SQL SERVER\Excel & Access\Select, Insert, Update & Delete\Northwind.mdb"
    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    conn.Open strConn

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        lastrow = .Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row
        lastcolumn = .Range("A2").End(xlToRight).Column
        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(lastrow, 1), .Cells(lastrow, lastcolumn))
    End With

        'therow = 1

        For i = 2 To lastrow
            'r = rng.Row
            'If r > 1 Then
                strSQL = "UPDATE PersonInformation SET " & _
                    "FName='" & Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & i).Value & "', " & _
                    "LName='" & Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & i).Value & "', " & _
                    "Address='" & Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & i).Value & "', " & _
                    "Age=" & Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E" & i).Value & " WHERE " & _
                    "ID=" & Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i).Value
                conn.Execute strSQL
            'End If
            'r = r + 1
        Next i


    conn.Close
    Set conn = Nothing
End Sub
```

[image]

There are so, so, so many different versions of this.  Hopefully you can adapt this example to fit your specific needs.